# F# - Can I reference "this" or "self" in a type provider?

Tags: f#, type-providers

I'm trying to create a type provider that inherits from this type:

```
type BaseType() =
    member val Member : string = "" with get, set
```

But I don't know how to reference Member using "this" or "base", say, in the constructor. Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
[<TypeProvider>]
type BasicProvider (config : TypeProviderConfig) as this =
    inherit TypeProviderForNamespaces ()

    let asm, ns = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), "Namespace"

    let createTypes () = 
        let myType = ProvidedTypeDefinition (asm, ns, "ProvidedType", Some typeof<BaseType>)
        let ctor =
            ProvidedConstructor [
                ProvidedParameter("inputString", typeof<string>) ]
        do ctor.InvokeCode <-
            fun parameters ->
                // base.Member doesn't actually work - how can one do this?
                <@@ do (base: BaseType).Member <- (%%parameters.[0]: string) @@>
        do myType.AddMembers [ctor]
        [myType]
    do this.AddNamespace(ns, createTypes())
```

**Is there any way to do what I'm trying to do when I say "base.Member" there?**

If not, is there a different recommended way to store internal state in a provided type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not tested this, but I think something like the following should do the trick:

```
ctor.InvokeCode <- fun parameters ->
  <@@ let res = BaseType()
      res.Member <- (%%parameters.[0]: string) 
      res @@>
```

The expression passed to `InvokeCode` of a constructor does not mean the *body* of a constructor of a new type (if you are creating erasing type provider) - it just needs to be any expression that returns a value of the type that you are erasing to. This means that you can put more complex initialization code in the expression.

I personally prefer keeping the inline quotations simpler, so I'd have a library function:

```
let createBaseType (input:string) = 
  BaseType(Member = input)
```

And call the helper from a quotation:

```
ctor.InvokeCode <- fun parameters ->  
  <@@ createBaseType (%%parameters.[0]) @@>
```

However, this is just a matter of style - both options should work.

Answer (score 2):

What I didn't realize in my original question is that the constructor needs to be a function that creates and returns an object of the type we're providing, not a constructor as we normally think about them. This makes self-reference much easier:

```
do ctor.InvokeCode <-
    fun parameters ->
        <@@
            let retVal = BaseType()
            retVal.Member <- (%%parameters.[0]: string)
            retVal @@>
```

Note that for properties and methods, parameter [0] is always the object itself ("`this`").

Comment: Haha, I just posted exactly the same thing, but there is an extra tip that's possibly worth keeping in a separate answer! :-)

Comment: Also note that there's syntax sugar for setting properties as if they were part of the constructor, so I think you can just do: `<@@ BaseType(Member = %%parameters.[0]) @@>`, which would desugar to basically the same thing you're writing out the long way.